# How to check Interconnection is available or not in j2me(Lwuit)

Tags: java-me

In my app I want to check gprsconnection using dialog in j2me(lwuit) can anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to open an address

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
  boolean result = false;
  HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
  try {
    httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
    result = true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: the above code doesn't execute any http call until you open the input stream of try to fetch the response code.

Comment: You don't need to execute any http call to check if Internet connection is available. You just need to see if you can create an HttpConnection. If there's no Internet profile, or if it's an invalid profile, then it will fail in creating the HttpConnection.